# Why does Server response with GET after a POST method request?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm stuck in in the middle of something:

**TL;DR** = I'm sending data through a **POST** request, but the server responses that I'm doing a **GET** request

I'm working with Laravel and Angular 1.5. Basically, in the view i have something like this.

This is my view:

```
<form name="formCrossedRelation" novalidate role="form"
ng-submit="createCrossedRelation(delivery_carrier_status)">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formCrossedRelation.configuration.$invalid && formCrossedRelation.configuration.$error.required && (formCrossedRelation.configuration.$dirty || formCrossedRelation.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formCrossedRelation.configuration.$valid || formCrossedRelation.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Carrier&nbsp;<small class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label>
            <select
                ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.delivery_carrier_status.carrier_id"
                required class="form-control" name="carrier"
                ng-options="item as item.name for item in carriers track by item.id"
                ng-change="getExternalStatuses(delivery_carrier_status.delivery_carrier_status.carrier_id)">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formCrossedRelation.configuration.$invalid && formCrossedRelation.configuration.$error.required && (formCrossedRelation.configuration.$dirty || formCrossedRelation.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formCrossedRelation.configuration.$valid || formCrossedRelation.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Estado Carrier&nbsp;<small
                class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label> <select
                ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.delivery_carrier_status.id"
                required class="form-control" name="externalStatuses"
                ng-options="item as item.code for item in externalStatuses track by item.id">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>


    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formCrossedRelation.configuration.$invalid && formCrossedRelation.configuration.$error.required && (formCrossedRelation.configuration.$dirty || formCrossedRelation.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formCrossedRelation.configuration.$valid || formCrossedRelation.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Estado EasyPoint&nbsp;<small
                class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label> <select
                ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.delivery_status.id" required
                class="form-control" name="EPstatus"
                ng-options="item as item.name for item in delivery_statuses track by item.id">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formPudo.full_address.$invalid && formPudo.full_address.$error.required && (formPudo.full_address.$dirty || formPudo.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formPudo.full_address.$valid || formPudo.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Operador 1&nbsp;<small
                class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label> <input
                class="form-control" name="full_address" type="text"
                ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.json_aditional[1]" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formCrossedRelation.configuration.$invalid && formCrossedRelation.configuration.$error.required && (formCrossedRelation.configuration.$dirty || formCrossedRelation.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formCrossedRelation.configuration.$valid || formCrossedRelation.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Operación&nbsp;<small class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label>
            <select ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.json_aditional.operator"
                class="form-control" name="operation"
                ng-options="item for item in operations track by item.id">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group"
            ng-class="{'has-error' :  formPudo.full_address.$invalid && formPudo.full_address.$error.required && (formPudo.full_address.$dirty || formPudo.$submitted) , 'has-success' : formPudo.full_address.$valid || formPudo.$submitted  }">
            <label for="">Operador 2&nbsp;<small
                class="text-danger font-noraml ">(*)</small></label> <input
                class="form-control" name="full_address" type="text"
                ng-model="delivery_carrier_status.json_aditional[2]" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-orange pull-right" ladda="loading.btnCreate"
            data-style="zoom-in" type="submit">Crear relación</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller in Angular

```
$scope.createCrossedRelation = function(delivery_carrier_status) {
    $scope.loading.btnCreate = true;
    if (this.formCrossedRelation.$valid) {
        delivery_carrier_status.json_aditional = JSON.stringify(delivery_carrier_status.json_aditional); 
        TrackingService.createCrossedRelation(delivery_carrier_status).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.status == 201) {
                $scope.delivery_carrier_statuses.unshift(response.data.status);
                delivery_carrier_status = {};
                $scope.modalcreateCrossedRelation = false;
                $scope.loading.btnCreate = false;

                Notification.success({
                    title : "¡Felicitaciones!",
                    message : "Correlación creada.",
                    template : "custom_template.html"
                });
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

            $scope.loading.btnCreate = false;
            if (response.status == 400) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    Notification.error({
                        title : "¡Oops!",
                        message : response.data[i],
                        template : "custom_template.html"
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        this.formCrossedRelation.$setPristine();
    } else {
        $scope.loading.btnCreate = false;
        Notification.error({
            title : "¡Oops!",
            message : 'No has completado todos los datos obligatorios del formulario.',
            template : "custom_template.html"
        });
    }
};
```

This is my TrackingService file

```
createCrossedRelation : function(delivery_carrier_status) {
        var req = {
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/api/statusconversion/',
            dataType : 'json',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            data : delivery_carrier_status
        }
        return $http(req);
    },
```

At this point, when I'm debugging, in the req variable, I'm getting this

[As you can see, I'm doing a POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNC5n.png)

But as soon as the backend responses, it is with a 405 status: Method not allowed

This is the routes.php file

```
        Route::post('api/statusconversion/', 'TrackingController@createDeliveryStatusCarrierStatus');
```

I don't know why i'm stucked. If anybody could help please.

Comment: where does `GET` come in? i don't see any headers or network tab screenshots showing the server responding as GET (which, by the way, doesn't make sense... the server doesn't respond with a particular method type... that's only for the request side.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api url, was misspelled. There was an extra "/"

Before:

```
createCrossedRelation : function(delivery_carrier_status) {
    var req = {
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/api/statusconversion/',
        dataType : 'json',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        data : delivery_carrier_status
    }
    return $http(req);
},
```

After:

```
createCrossedRelation : function(delivery_carrier_status) {
    var req = {
        method : 'POST',
        url : '/api/statusconversion', // Without the "/"
        dataType : 'json',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        data : delivery_carrier_status
    }
    return $http(req);
},
```